# Modality of spiritual power transfer

Tags: shakti, spirituality

At the time of slaying [Hiranyakasipu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiranyakashipu)  it was estimated that power of Vishnu alone was insufficient to counter the Rakshas due many clever boons he received from Brahma to ensure impossibility of his own death. So the *amsa* of Shiva had to be added to Vishnu's active Avatar for the attack.

How is the power invoked for transference ? By prayer? manthras of yagnya or thanthra? by voluntary intention from a higher power source? Or is it by *request for action through the power of Bhakthi* like Prahlad's towards Vishnu? Or Gajendra's to Vishnu?

The power of Bhakthi is a strong belief even in modern times, so this question.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Where did you hear that Shiva's power was added to Narasimha?

Comment: forgot it... was in a para discussing such matters in Telugu. Shall intimate if found.Google not helpful

Comment: @Narasimham Where did you hear such story? Is this any legend of temple in AP?

Comment: I shall report it here when found. But cannot vouch for a credible reference out of a Purana. We know half truths are used to instill Bhakthi among skeptics and it has some sanction.  In all faiths highly spiritual and enlightened souls time and again used or showed a  faculty to voluntary energy transfer. Saint Thyagaraja, Saint Francis of Assisi, Sai Baba of Shirdi, Jesus Christ are among them.

Comment: @Destroyer Traditionally Narasimha is said to protect temples, and lion heads are carved and installed in several temples.Apart from that I do not know of any particular temple Sthala Purana.